# I want that when the object is hovered, a JS function should run, but it runs immediately on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I have a card with the class `services-box`, I just want, whenever the card is hovered, for my function to run.

This is my JS code:

```js
var services_box = document.querySelectorAll('.services-box');
services_box.addEventListener("mouseover", hover_bx(), false);

function hover_bx() {
  alert("asdasdasdasd")
}
```

```html
<div class="services-box">
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="{% static 'main/images/videoproduction.png' %}" alt="design.png" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h5>Video Production</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ducimus quia sint impedit autem quis magnam, exercitationem consequatur dolorum accusamus consectetur quidem quod minima laudantium?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`hover_bx()` is calling function immediately.

You need to pass only reference to function (name of function)

```js
(function () {
    var services_box = document.querySelector('.services-box');
    services_box.addEventListener("mouseover", hover_bx, false); 

    function hover_bx () {
        alert("asdasdasdasd")
    }
})();
```

```html
<div class="services-box">Hover me!</div>
```

Comment: Also, use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`

Comment: `services_box = document.querySelectorAll('.services-box')` is array, if you have some services_box, run `services_box.forEach(function(service){  service.addEventListener("mouseover", hover_bx, false);   })` instead.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Sorry, copy-pasted from OP question

Comment: Thanks It works perfectly , I just wanted to ask if I had multiple elements with the same class and wanted every one should have this feature , how to do it.

Comment: @NISHANTPacharne Then use `.querySelectorALL` to get all elements, loop all of them and add event to each element

Comment: @NISHANTPacharne Or consider using jQuery to easier your life :D